# CodeIgniter Hosting

Tags: codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Where can I find affordable web hosting for Codeigniter web application? I need hosting that supports all the PHP extensions that Codeigniter requires? Anyone recommend a dependable company?

Comment: can u be specific about the extensions ?

Answer (score 1):

Almost any webhosting company is sufficient for hosting codeigniter apps. They support almost all the extensions the ci uses.

Few
[godaddy](http://www.godaddy.com),
[ipage](http://www.ipage.com)

Answer (score 1):

Any hosting company that supports PHP can be used to host a CodeIgniter app. If you want someone who specifically hosts CodeIgniter apps, then take a look at [Cloud Igniter](http://www.getcloudigniter.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Most web hosting companies' PHP installs will support CodeIgniter. Personally, I really like [1and1](http://1and1.com) hosting. It is very affordable, and, IMHO, way better than goDaddy.